# Set Apects via REST API Call in Alfresco

Tags: alfresco, alfresco-share

What is the JSON Format to set aspects to some folder or documents in alfresco via REST API.

Comment: there is no json format like that.You neeed to make one webscript.Or use the inbuilt one

Comment: I found an inbuild API for Managing Aspects:
Below are the details  :

POST /alfresco/s/slingshot/doclib/action/aspects/node/{store_type}/{store_id}/{id}
---
Document List Component - aspects submit
---
Authentication: user
Transaction: required
Format Style: argument
Default Format: json
Lifecycle: internal
Id: org/alfresco/slingshot/documentlibrary/action/aspects.post
Descriptor: classpath:alfresco/templates/webscripts/org/alfresco/slingshot/documentlibrary/action/aspects.post.desc.xml

Comment: @KrutikJayswal But I couldnt find the proper josn format for this API

Comment: Reply of Sergey Palyukh will be usefull in that case.

Comment: If its still not working look into the code. using below URL.http://localhost:8080/alfresco/service/script/org/alfresco/slingshot/documentlibrary/action/aspects.post

Answer (score 1):

You need to send POST request by the following url (Alfresco 4.1.5):

```
your_host/alfresco/s/slingshot/doclib/action/aspects/node/workspace/SpacesStore/{nodeUUID}
```

for Alfresco 5:

```
your_host/alfresco/s/slingshot/doclib/action/aspects/node/workspace/SpacesStore/{nodeUUID}
```

with the following body:

```
{
   "added":["abc:doc"],
   "removed":[]
}
```

[image]

Comment: when using GET method i'm able to get the current aspects for that {nodeUID}

this is the response

`{
   "current": ["cm:auditable","cm:titled","rn:renditioned","cm:author","cm:versionable"]
}`

But when im using the post with the given Json format the below is the response
`405 Description: The method specified in the Request-Line is not allowed for the resource identified by the Request-URI.
 Message: 02020006 Script url /slingshot/doclib/aspects/node/workspace/SpacesStore/db16a722-d850-47a9-8237-52cebdb651e0 does not support the method POST`

Comment: Sorry, you are right. It doesn't work for Alfresco 5 (tested on 4.1.5).  
You need to use this url: /alfresco/s/slingshot/doclib/action/aspects/node/workspace/SpacesStore/{nodeUUID}

Comment: **The method specified in the Request-Line is not allowed** this is the reply im getting from the API

Comment: You need to set request header "Content-Type" to "application/json". Take a look at image that I added to my answer.

Comment: Please find the screenshots of my requests and responses.
[GET ASPECTS](http://pasteboard.co/1y1OWQig.png)
[POST ASPECT](http://pasteboard.co/1y218sZr.png)
i used content type as application/json.Still the error is there.

Comment: Thank you Sergey. I got It. There was an error in the URL.

Answer (score 1):

The preferred approach is to use CMIS rather than the internal slingshot web script. Using CMIS you can add an aspect in a standard way, and you can do it via the browser binding (JSON), the Atom Pub binding (XML), or Web Services.

You can use a CMIS client, such as one of the ones available from http://chemistry.apache.org, or you can do it using the raw binding directly over HTTP.

In CMIS 1.1 you add an aspect by adding its ID to the multi-value property named cmis:secondaryObjectTypeIds.

Here's a gist that shows what this looks like in Java: https://gist.github.com/jpotts/7242070

Answer (score 0):

You need to make one custom webscript.The code of webscript will be like below.In case of webscript you can use below link for learning purpose.

https://wiki.alfresco.com/wiki/Web_Scripts

```
var props = new Array(1);
props["cm:template"] = document.nodeRef;
document.addAspect("cm:templatable", props);

props = new Array(1);
props["cm:lockIsDeep"] = true;
document.addAspect("cm:lockable", props);

props = new Array(1);
props["cm:hits"] = 1;
document.addAspect("cm:countable", props);
```